# Set of measurable preimages is $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f(x,y)=x-y$ and $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $S'=\{(x,y) :f(x,y)\in S\}$. Now let $\mathscr{M}=\{S:S'$ is measurable$\}$. Show that $\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I have shown two conditions. But I'm having trouble showing if $S\in \mathscr{M}$ then $S^C\in \mathscr{M}$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you find a relation between $S^{\prime}$ and $(S^C)^{\prime}$?

Comment: @Thorgott They are complements of each other correct?

Comment: @catmybreat Then if $(S^C)' = (S')^C$, you want to show $S^C \in \mathcal{M}$, which is the same as $(S^C)'$ measurable, and hence the same as $(S')^C$ measurable. Is $(S')^C$ measurable?

Comment: @catmybreat Your question only make sense when you specify what we require $S'$ to be measurable with respect to. E.g. you can say the Borel $\sigma$-algebra or something like that.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Are there certain things that $(S')^C$ would not be measurable wrt? What if it was just a Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @catmybreat I don't understand what you're asking. My second comment is about how you technically must fix a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ to give meaning to the statement "$S'$ is measurable". My first comment is helping you solve your problem, assuming some such $\sigma$-algebra is fixed. What do you mean by "certain things that $(S')^C$ would not be measurable w/r/t"? $A$ is measurable w/r/t the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{N}$ is a long way of say $A \in \mathcal{N}$. This is precisely what is meant by measurable. Hence the necessity of fixing a $\sigma$-algebra from the start.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Ok thank you! I think that makes sense. Sorry, still new to all this.

Comment: @catmybreat I added my answer as an actual answer (which is probably what I should've done in the first place). Please mark as accepted (if it is) so this question is resolved.

Comment: I have undeleted this question. I notice that you deleted this question shortly after receiving an answer. This is very unkind to your answerer and to later visitors of the site.  It also makes it appear as though you are trying to hide something. **Don't do that**.

Answer (score 1):

If $(S^C)' = (S')^C$, you want to show $S^C \in \mathcal{M}$, which is the same as $(S^C)'$ measurable, hence the same as $(S')^C measurable. Is (S')^C measurable?

Note: Your question only make sense when you specify what we require $S'$ to be measurable with respect to. E.g. you can say the Borel $\sigma$-algebra or something like that.